# why this directive does not execute factory's function in angular 1.5?

Tags: angularjs

What is the problem with this factory and the directive?

```
app.factory('myTools', function() {
  return {
    days: function() { return 31; }
  };
}) ;

app.directive('listDays', ['myTools',function(myTools){
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>days = {{myTools.days()}}</div>'
   }
}]);
```

The following html does not work

```
<list-days></list-days>
```

displaying only

```
days =
```

See Plinker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HWU2dGclzbZHzzmO9ise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can keep it all in your directive if you'd like. It's just because the factory method isn't a scoped variable. Just have to make it accessible to the view with $scope somehow.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('myTools', function() {
  return {
    days: function() {
      return 31;
    }
  };
});

function ListDays(myTools) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>days = {{days}}</div>',
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.days = myTools.days();
    }
  };
}
app.directive('listDays', ListDays);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

**Edit:**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('myTools', function() {
  return {
    days: function() {
      return 31;
    }
  };
});

function ListDays(myTools) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>days = {{myTools.days()}}</div>',
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.myTools = myTools;
    }
  };
}
app.directive('listDays', ListDays);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean that I cannot use `myTools` directly but rather copy all the values and functions?

Comment: Oh! I see! I can do the following in the link function: `$scope.myTools = myTools;` and then use `myTools` just like that! If you correct your answer to use myTools variable instead of copying days then I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was scratching my head for an hour or so to find the reason this does not work!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1.Inject factory into Ctrl- MainCtrl
2.Create scope variable - days and use it in your directive
3.As directive in your code uses the parent scope(controller/directive inside which it lies)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('myTools', function() {
  return {
    days: function() { return 31; }
  };
}) ;

app.directive('listDays', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>days = {{days}}</div>'
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,myTools) {
  $scope.days = myTools.days();
});
```

Plunker- http://plnkr.co/edit/Kny9SSp7c0yyc3ItVXvy?p=preview

**Updated:** Independent directive by injecting factory to directive link scope

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('myTools', function() {
  return {
    days: function() { return 31; }
  };
}) ;

app.directive('listDays', ['myTools',function(myTools){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>days = {{days}}</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.days = myTools.days();
        }
  }
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

Plunker- http://plnkr.co/edit/Fh9i2FqbglPHWIBYRsVm?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This depends on the main controller, while I would like to keep it 'standalone' so I could use it in other places.